# Is there any event on authentication ticket expired? ASP.NET

Tags: forms-authentication

I need to do some cleaning when an authentication ticket is expired. 
Is there any event that i can subscribe to?

Thanks for any suggestions,
HF

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET events happen when the user does something, causing a postback to the server.  The authentication ticket expiring doesn't cause a postback, hence no way for you to know.  You'll have to keep track of the time on your own.